# Fail to replace kubernetes statefulsets using io.fabric8.kubernetes-client

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I use io.fabric8.kubernetes-client, version 3.1.8 to create or replace kubernetes resource. It is fine to create or replace Deployment. But I meet an exception when replace StatefulSet. But it is fine if I use 'kubectl apply -f pro-rabbitmq.yaml'

> Failure executing: PUT at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/apis/apps/v1beta1/namespaces/itsma1/statefulsets/pro-rabbitmq. Message: StatefulSet.apps "pro-rabbitmq" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden.. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=422, details=StatusDetails(causes=[StatusCause(field=spec, message=Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden., reason=FieldValueForbidden, additionalProperties={})], group=apps, kind=StatefulSet, name=pro-rabbitmq, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=StatefulSet.apps "pro-rabbitmq" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden., metadata=ListMeta(resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Invalid, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you do to trigger that error?

Comment: I updated the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311911/forbidden-updates-to-statefulset-spec-for-fields-other-than-replicas-templa

Comment: Could you please share code snippet from which you're trying to update statefulset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311911/forbidden-updates-to-statefulset-spec-for-fields-other-than-replicas-templa)