# Fail to replace kubernetes statefulsets using fabric8 maven plugin

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

We use fabric8-maven-plugin to manage the full lifecycle of all of our kubernetes services. We are having a problem upgrading statefulsets (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295784/fail-to-replace-kubernetes-statefulsets-using-io-fabric8-kubernetes-client) post but we dont use the kubernetes-client). The version of the maven plugin is 4.3.1. We have no issues with daemonsets but I just cant find a way to update statefulsets. We get the same error as the afore mentioned post.

```
Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden..
```

I have tried to set the updateStrategy to rolling but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks Paul

Comment: Hi, Are you able to reproduce this with 4.4.0 also?

Comment: Hi Rohan, I just had a go using 4.4.0 and the outcome is the same.

Comment: ah, Could you please file an issue on our repo? I far as I remember there was some bug in kubernetes client which was causing this. https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/1880

Comment: we upgraded k8s-client in January, so I think it should solve this issue : https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/pull/1774

Comment: Could you please file an issue with reproducible sample? We will fix this before next release.

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I will raise an issue asap.

Comment: Much appreciated, Thanks! Bdw, We are working towards rebranding FMP to https://github.com/eclipse/jkube . Would appreciate if you could try this out and share some feedback.

Comment: Hi Rohan, I raised an issue in the fabric8-maven-plugin [repo](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/issues/1795)